# Apache2 Server and Forwarding Two Ports On the Router

Tags: apache, sockets, server, port, forwarding

Hope everyone is doing well.

This is probably one of those newbie questions so please bear with me.

I have an index.php webpage hosted by Apache server (Virtual Host port 80). I'm able to access it via web browser by typing in the local IP of the machine the server is installed on. 
I have another webpage which has a camera stream. This camera stream was configured to be running on a different port (5005).
Both webpages are saved in the same /var/www/ directory.

The camera stream is embedded on the index.php website. This arrangement works well locally, I can see the stream just fine when I type in my local IP address into the browser.

Now, it'd great to have the index.php webpage accessible over the internet. I decided to go with the router port forwarding technique but now I'm facing a problem. 
Will the camera stream embedded on the index.php webpage still be visible if I only forward ports 80 and 443 on my router? Will the server still be able to see it as it was able to in a local environment?

Would be great if you guys could help me out here.

Kind regards
Rob

Answer (score 0):

The web server will see the camera stream the same way as when you make requests locally. But whether your setup will work depends on if the web *browser* needs to connect to the camera stream directly (on port 5005). If it does, you will need to forward also the port 5005, or make the stream available through the web server in some way so that the browser only needs to use port 80 or 443.

Comment: Hi Joni. Thanks for your reply! Let's say the browser does need to connect to the camera stream directly. In what way would I forward the port and still have the camera stream visible on the webpage? Would I need to embed it by referring to the external IP and its port, <iframe src: xxx.xxx.x.x:5005></iframe>? Thanks again!

Comment: Is this an IP camera that's accepting connections on port 5005? You would forward the port 5005 on the router to the camera's IP and port, and change the src on the web page to the public external IP address